# rename query field when using with entity manager

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Can anyone help me,  I'm new to Spring Jpa
I want to change field name when using Native query, but when i do as below it display erorr.

```
EntityManager entityManager;

String query =
 "SELECT cus.id, pLead.id leadId, cus.code custCode, cus.primaryName custName, " + 
 "cus.primaryKhmerName custkhmerName, pLead.phoneNo, prot.englishName propertyType, " + 
 "pro.houseno houseNo, pro.streetno streetNo, pLead.address " +   
 "FROM Customer cus, Contract con, Property pro, PropertyType prot, Lead pLead " + 
 "WHERE cus.id = con.customer AND prot.id = pro.propertyType AND pro.id = con.property AND cus.primaryLead = pLead.id "; 

List<Object> results = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

**Error log**

```
13:48:03,698  ERROR [internal.ast.ErrorCounter] line 1:25: unexpected token: leadId
13:48:03,710  ERROR [internal.ast.ErrorCounter] line 1:25: unexpected token: leadId
line 1:25: unexpected token: leadId
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3556)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3250)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.multiplyExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3122)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.additiveExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2828)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:568)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2595)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2456)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2420)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2336)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2011)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.aliasedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2254)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectedPropertiesList(HqlBaseParser.java:1391)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1294)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1031)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1778)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.bnd.rems.service.SearchServiceImp.getSearchCustomer(SearchServiceImp.java:59)
    at com.bnd.rems.service.NoneTradeServiceImp.removeItem(NoneTradeServiceImp.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.removeItem(Unknown Source)
    at com.bnd.rems.controller.NoneTradeController.removeItem(NoneTradeController.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put the SQL keyword `AS` between your column name and the aliases like this:

```
String query =
 "SELECT cus.id, pLead.id AS leadId, cus.code AS custCode, cus.primaryName AS custName, " + 
 "cus.primaryKhmerName AS custkhmerName, pLead.phoneNo, prot.englishName AS propertyType, " + 
 "pro.houseno AS houseNo, pro.streetno AS streetNo, pLead.address " +   
 "FROM Customer cus, Contract con, Property pro, PropertyType prot, Lead pLead " + 
 "WHERE cus.id = con.customer AND prot.id = pro.propertyType AND pro.id = con.property AND cus.primaryLead = pLead.id ";
```

It is always a good practice to use the `AS` keyword because it is the SQL-92 standard.

Comment: it *is* good practice, but then he isn't specifying SQL there (and those are field names not column names), it's JPQL ... though your advice does actually apply there too.

Comment: Yes, you're right, in fact I mixed the two language because JPQL derive from SQL (select property from entity instead select columns from table).